# Get rows that are not logged in a joined table

Tags: mysql

[image: tables]

I got this 3 tables as shown aboved.

My goal is to get all `bits` that `user` 1 (jm) did not put a reaction to.

Currently I have this MySQL code:

```
select * from bit b LEFT JOIN bit_reaction br ON (br.bitId=b.id AND br.userId != 1)
```

The problem here is that `bit_reaction`.id = 2 is being returned since br.userId is not equal to 1. The correct behavior is that it would only return bits with id 2 and 3.

Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.*
from bit b
left join bit_reaction br ON br.bitId = b.id 
                         AND br.userId = 1
WHERE br.bitId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want every user to react every bit. So the more generic answer will be...

```
SELECT *
FROM bit AS tBit
LEFT JOIN user AS tUser ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN bit_reaction AS tReaction ON tBit.id = tReaction.bitID
    AND tUser.id = tReaction.userID
WHERE tReaction.userID IS NULL
```